# What is the laplace transform of the below given PDF?

Tags: distributions, self-study, moments, signal-processing, transform

Really am interesting to know more about statistical properties of the following PDF , of the Random variable $z$:
$$F(\sigma,\mu,z)= \frac{(z-\sigma )^2 \exp \left(-\frac{(z-\sigma )^2
   \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{\mu ^2}{400}\right) 2 \pi } \text{erf}\left(\frac{(z-\sigma
   )^2 \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{\mu ^2}{400}\right) 2 \pi }}{1+\frac{\mu
   ^2}{400}}\right)}{1+\frac{\mu ^2}{400}}\right)}{0.0994735 \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{\mu
   ^2}{400}\right) 2 \pi }}  $$
such that $\mu$ lie in $(0,1)$ , Some Properties  related to that PDF which montioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212259/66737) are : The Mean is 0 and the odd moments also are zero which implies skewness is zero , and that PDF present a symetric distribution as shown in the first plot  which means that is a Gaussian and probably it is a bell curve ,and the second plot of that distribution  present probability plot VS probability of Normal distribution ,  Now I seek to know if I can get the laplace transform of that PDF for $\mu=0$ , and $\sigma=0$  May also  the formula of moment generating function for the titled conditions ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you replaced the actual numbers by short symbols like „a,b,c,...“ as the definition itself is then easier to read and you will probably end up with a general description for the Laplace Transform (i.e. an expression where you can easily substitute the concrete numbers by other numbers) in any case...

Comment: You'll need to update $F$ with a different constant to have it be a pdf (as the necessary constant depends on $\mu$).

Comment: @JimB, But i have took the formula as it were posted in mathematica forum answer , what normalization i should do now ? or you meant that i should change that formula completly ?

Comment: @FabianWerner, Pleas could u explain more what i should replace ?

Comment: In the above formula you have $0.0025\mu^2$ instead of $0.25\mu^2$, there is a $\pi!+6-\pi$ which comes from nowhere, there is $F(\sigma,\mu)$ when it should be $F(z,\sigma,\mu)$, and I don't know where the $0.999359291501$ comes from.  The point is that you need the give the pdf rather than just some unknown multiple of the pdf or don't call it a pdf.

Comment: @JimB, Thanks i have plug ancient formula now , it fixed look it and thanks for your attention

Comment: What you have is "close" for value $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=0$ but not close at all for values of $\mu=10$, for example.  We've gone around and around with this in other forums and I need to move on to other things.

Comment: This is the problem this pdf is valid only for mu in the range (0,1), I have tried to  get it arbitrary but that pdf dosn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102822/discussion-between-jimb-and-zeraoulia-rafik).

Comment: Looks vaguely like $\frac{1}{X}\sim\mathcal{N}_{\frac{1}{x}}(0,\sigma)$, i.e., the reciprocal of a normally distributed random variable with mean zero. Bimodal with median zero, but Cauchy like without a mean or variance of the PDF. What gave rise to this?